# Let $a,b,c$ be integers, then exactly one of the statements $a > b$, $a < b$ or $a = b$ is true.

Tags: definition, solution-verification, integers

**MY ATTEMPT**

Given two integers $a,b$, there is just one possibility among three: $a - b$ is zero; $a - b$ is a positive natural number $n$; or $a - b$ is the negation of a positive natural number $n$. In the first case, one has $a = b$; in the second case, one has that $a - b = n > 0$, that is to say, $a > b$; in the third case, $a - b = -n$, that is to say, $b = a + n$, thus $b > a$.

Could someone verify if I am reasoning rightly?

**EDIT**

The main result on which I am basing my answer is:

**Trichotomy of integers**

Let $x$ be an integer. Then exactly one of the following three statements is true: (a) $x$ is zero; (b) $x$ is equal to a positive natural number $n$; or (c) $x$ is the negation $-n$ of a positive natural number $n$.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: What are your definitions and axioms?

Comment: I have edited my answer in order to provide the context from whence this problem comes.

Comment: The your axiom is the trichotomy of integers and you definition of "$>$" is $a > b \iff a-b >0$ then your reasoning is fine.